# Can you import Selenium Web driver into the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

The company I am working with is trying to get rid of most of its IT infrastructure so that they don't need any more servers. I have been asked to develop a program that takes information from a Google spreadsheet and then with this information puts it into a web browser. I am planning on using Python and the Selenium web driver. Will I be able to install Selenium if I host the application as a Google app engine?

The reason I want/need to use the Selenium web driver is that I need to put the information from Google into a legacy system. The only way to put information in the system is to mimic a user typing the information manually in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you think Selenium will be doing here. It seems a very strange way to want to get information from one Google property into another.

Google spreadsheets have a [perfectly good API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) that allows you to read the data from your app and display it to users.

**Edit after question update** Well, now I don't see what you need GAE for. That is for hosting and running websites, and you only seem to want to enter data into an existing website. That's not what it does at all.

Comment: I edited my original post, but to summarize. Instead of people put in information into the legacy system I want to automate it with a webdriver.

Comment: So what are the specific problems you are having with using that java library? (This is why I downvoted your question)

Comment: I am asking if it is even possible to do what I am trying to do. Can you integrate selenium web driver into a google application.

Comment: Well, no. It needs the ability to control a local instance of a web browser, and you can't run a browser inside GAE (and even if you could, you'd then have to poke a hole in your firewall to give it access to your legacy intranet application).